# JQuery Mobile panel menu. Pages not linking

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to use the panel feature from JQuery mobile, and after following some tutorials I cannot make the panel to link the pages within my app to work, and it just stays at the first page  The animation works fine tho´. Any suggesting of how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
<body>
<!--Activity Feed Page-->        
        <div id="activityFeed" data-role="page"> 
            <!--Panel-->            
                <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a" class="ui-response">
                    <div data-role="listview" class="nav-seacrh">
                        <li><a href="#activityFeed"data-rel="close">Activity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#messagesPage"data-rel="close">Messages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#profilePage" data-rel="close">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#settingsPage"data-rel="close">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-rel="close">Log out</a></li>               
                    </div>
                </div> <!--ends panel-->            
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Activity Feed</h1>
                <a href="#myPanel" data-icon="bars" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext">Panel</a>
            </div>
            <p>Activity Feed Page</p>       
        </div>
<!--End Feed Page-->

<!--Messages  Page-->
        <div id="messagesPage"data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Messages</h1>
                <a href="#myPanel" data-icon="bars" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext">Panel</a>
            </div>  
            <p>Messages Page</p>                                                  
        </div>
<!--Ends Messages Page-->

<!--Profile Page-->
        <div id="profilePage"data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Profile</h1>
            <a href="#myPanel" data-icon="bars" data-role="buttons"data-iconpos="notext">Panel</a>  
            </div>
            <div>   
            <p>Profile Page</p>
            </div>


        </div>
<!--Ends Settings Page-->
        <div id="settingsPage"data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Settings Feed</h1>
        <a href="#myPanel" data-icon="bars" data-role="buttons" data-iconpos="notext">Panel</a> 
                </div>
                <div>
                <p>Settings Page</p>
                </div>


        </div>
 <!--Ends Settings Page-->
```

Comment: Remove data-rel=close

Answer (score 0):

The `data-rel="close"` inside your page links is causing JQM to override their click handlers to close the panel.

Remove that and it should navigate to page mentioned in `href`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks Nirmal, but it supposed to be possible to close and at the same time link to your page according to JQ mobile doc: 
    `<a href="#my-header" data-rel="close">Close panel</a>`

Comment: That should be only on one link - specifically to close the panel. Not on the links to other pages.

Comment: Oh! Ok, yes. I thought it was possible to have links to navigate from one page to another page like tinder app does ;(.